# Passing a variable from one class to paintComponent class

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

my first time here and total newbie. I have two classes in my program, the first class SwingPaintDemo2 and the second class MyPanel. MyPanel contains my paintComponent(Graphics g) method. I have a boolean variable in my first class called isTrue. I want to make it so that if isTrue = true; then paintComponent executes g.fillRect(l, w, 50, 50). Believe me, I have googled and googled and googled......

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingPaintDemo2 extends JComponent {

public static boolean isTrue = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
    JPanel MyPanel = new JPanel();
     MyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000));
     MyPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 200));
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.add(new MyPanel());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

}

}

class MyPanel extends JComponent {

public MyPanel() {
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(250,200);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    int l = 30;
    int w = 30;

    if (SwingPaintDemo2.isTrue){g.setColor(Color.black); 
  g.fillRect(l, w, 50, 50);}


}  
}
```

how do I get my isTrue variable to my paintComponent class (getting variable not found error in paintComponent class)? Thanks in advance for any help.

Update: I have just posted my most recent code above after making the changes suggested earlier. Now I am getting "cannot find symbol - variable isTrue", any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a public static variable, always refer to it using the name of the enclosing class (and not by recreating a new instance of your SwingPaintDemo2 class):

```
SwingPaintDemo2.isTrue
```

You should try to avoid static variables.

Now, maybe you meant to declare a constant, then you need to declare it `final`

```
public static final boolean isTrue = true;
```

Finally, I see also a suspicious line:

```
if (isTrue=true)
```

which should rather be

```
if (isTrue)
```

NB: variables should start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: thks again Guillame. The reason I used static is because I tried a lot of things and thought maybe that would help. I don't want to declare a constant (final) because next I am going to write code in SwingPaintDemo2 class that will decide weather isTrue is true or false. I have replaced     'code'if (isTrue=true){g.setColor(Color.black); 
  g.fillRect(l, w, 50, 50);}
with 'code' if (SwingPaintDemo2.isTrue){g.setColor(Color.black); 
      g.fillRect(l, w, 50, 50);} and also I have commented out 'code'SwingPaintDemo2 PaintDemo = new SwingPaintDemo2();

Answer (score 0):

Since `isTrue` is a static member of `SwingPaintDemo2` class, you can access this without instantiating a new object i.e. `SwingPaintDemo2.isTrue`

So your code will look like:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    int l = 30;
    int w = 30;
   SwingPaintDemo2 PaintDemo = new SwingPaintDemo2();


    if (SwingPaintDemo2.isTrue == true){
        g.setColor(Color.black); 
        g.fillRect(l, w, 50, 50);
    }


}
```

Comment: `if (SwingPaintDemo2.isTrue =true)` will always be true since you are assigning true to `isTrue` and then you evaluate the value of `isTrue`. You probably meant `if (SwingPaintDemo2.isTrue)`

Comment: thks for replies, Waqas, Guillaume. I have tried both suggestions : if (SwingPaintDemo2.isTrue =true) and if (SwingPaintDemo2.isTrue). I agree with Guillaume's modification to Waqas's suggestion. Regardless, either way I am still getting "cannot find symbol - variable isTrue"

Comment: GuillaumePolet thanks yes I have edited it..
@user1894469 are you using if(SwingPaintDemo2.isTrue == true) or just if (isTrue == true)?

Comment: well now my code is as follows:public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        int l = 30;
        int w = 30;
       //SwingPaintDemo2 PaintDemo = new SwingPaintDemo2();
       //PaintDemo().isWall;
        
        
       //boolean isWall = true;
        if (SwingPaintDemo2.isTrue){g.setColor(Color.black); 
      g.fillRect(l, w, 50, 50);}

        // Draw Text
        
        //g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
    }

Comment: never to create whatever `Object` in `paintComponent` (`SwingPaintDemo2 PaintDemo = new SwingPaintDemo2();`), prepare those `Objects` before,

Comment: Thks mKorbel, but I have modified my code and removed that line. If you look at the code in my original question right on top, I modified the code there so not creating an object in paintComponent anymore, but still getting error "cannot find symbol - variable isTrue". sorry my first time posting so sometimes I may not be clear. Appreciate your help.